# Read file line by line and save in different strings

Tags: java

I need to read f_name,l_name, username, password from .txt file and save these information in different strings.

Here is code that i found for read line by line:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Users {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
   File file = new File("users.txt");
   FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
   BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
   StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
   String line;
   while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuffer.append(line);
    stringBuffer.append("\n");
   }
   fileReader.close();
   System.out.println("Contents of file:");
   System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

but I don't know how to every first name save in variable f_name, every last name in variable l_name,...
Every of this f_name, l_name, username, password are in new line in file.

Example of file with datas:

```
John

Johnson

johny

1234

David

Davidson

davy

1234

...
```

Comment: use `if` condition with a variable as counter in `while`.

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer as it was replaced by StringBuilder more than ten years ago.

Comment: You want to read four lines at a time and assignment to four different variables.  I suggest you try that. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Every of this f_name, l_name, username, password are in new line in file.

You can read four lines at a time like this

```
String f_name = bufferedReader.readLine();
String l_name = bufferedReader.readLine();
String username = bufferedReader.readLine();
String password = bufferedReader.readLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Add this line:

```
private BufferedReader innerReader;
```

And use this method:

```
private List<String> loadFile(Reader reader)
        throws IllegalArgumentException, IOException{
    List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(reader == null)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Reader non valido");
    }
    String line;
    innerReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
    try
    {
    while((line = innerReader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line == null || line.trim().isEmpty())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Line Empty");
        fileList.add(line);
    }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IOException(e);
    }
    return fileList;
}
```

Then in main:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
            myList = myClass.loadFile(new FileReader("YourFile.txt"));
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for(String s : myList)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    try {
        myClass.innerReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Output:

> John
>
> Johnson
>
> johny
>
> 1234
>
> David
>
> Davidson
>
> davy
>
> 1234

Comment: Your first method doesn't throw `FileNotFoundException`. What is the benefit of wrapping a checked exception with an unchecked one if the first you do is catch it again?

Comment: Please don't use a `static` variable which could be set by different threads. esp which a local variable would be simpler, faster and clearer.

Comment: Yes, I wrote it quickly, now I change it.

Comment: I edited , I know you could do a class dedicated only to read from file, and much more, then it is at the discretion of the programmer. @PeterLawrey

Comment: Why do you wrap an IOException with another IOException?  In stead of passing a Reader to `loadFile` you could pass a file name like `Files.readAllLines(Path)` does.